# Including C functions and headers in C++ program

Tags: c++, c, xcode, apache, module

I'm trying to build an apache module in C++ and I think I'm just missing something.  I'm running XCode 5.1, OSX 10.9.  I've built Apache 2.4 successfully and have all the libs/headers etc.  I've successfully compiled several modules using C, apxs, and the aforementioned libs/headers.  I've read about extern "C" and I believe i understand that.  So, why when I try to compile my C++ module (which has no complaints about unknown/missing headers) do I get linker errors for undefined symbols.  Am I missing something about calling C functions from inside C functions defined in a C++ file?  I used this tutorial as a reference:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491909/Apache-x-Modules-In-Cplusplus-Part

It compiles fine if I take out the ap_* funcs.  I've also tried wrapping my includes in extern "C" as well with no luck.  Also, my successful attempts with just C were compiled with apxs where as here I would like to compile the .so with XCode and install via apxs.  What gives?

Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
//
//  mod_mm2.h
//  mod_mm2
//
//  Created by Tony Stark on 9/2/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Tony Stark. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef __mod_mm2__mod_mm2__
#define __mod_mm2__mod_mm2__

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERN_C_BLOCK_BEGIN    extern "C" {
#define EXTERN_C_BLOCK_END      }
#define EXTERN_C_FUNC           extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERN_C_BLOCK_BEGIN
#define EXTERN_C_BLOCK_END
#define EXTERN_C_FUNC
#endif


#include <httpd.h>
#include <http_protocol.h>
#include <http_config.h>

#endif /* defined(__mod_mm2__mod_mm2__) */
```

and the cpp

```
#include "mod_mm2.h"



EXTERN_C_FUNC int mm2_handler(request_rec *r)
{

    /* Do we want to handle this request? */
    if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "mm2_module") != 0) {

        /* No */
        return DECLINED;
    }

    /* Is this a method we accept? */
    if (r->method_number != M_GET) {

        /* No. */
        return HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;
    }


    ap_set_content_type(r, "text/html");

    ap_rputs("<h1>Handler working</h1>", r);

    return OK;


};



EXTERN_C_FUNC void mm2_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{

    ap_hook_handler(mm2_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_FIRST);
};



EXTERN_C_BLOCK_BEGIN
module AP_DECLARE_DATA mm2_module = {

    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    mm2_hooks
};
EXTERN_C_BLOCK_END
```

Comment: What type is request_rec? (user-defined class, struct, etc)

Comment: The `extern "C"` statements are needed around the headers declaring the functions you want to call, not around the calling code.

Comment: @MiyazawaKenji The request_rec is the standard request struct.  I should have included that I have tried adding extern "C" around my includes as well.